# Creating JSON object from text file values

Tags: javascript, json, public-suffix-list

I want to convert the plaintext [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/) to JSON object so as to use it in my script. I just want the list of TLD's.
The list is here https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat
My initial thought was to regex match the file for suffix list but I don't know how to regex files in javascript. I'm kind of new to javascript.

Anyone having idea, how to achieve this. Thank You

Comment: The suffix list is a list, so it should rather be loaded into an array, rather than an object, no? Or what structure do you want the object to have?

Comment: that's what I want to know How to convert that list in JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the list doesn't seem to be allowed to do cross-domain, so direct AJAX to the resource isn't possible.

What you can do is have your server load it for you (PHP: [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents), JS: [`http.get`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)). Then, implement a parser. I'm not familiar with the format of the file, but you can read the file line by line, skip blank lines and lines with `//`. Then load them into an array (PHP: `array_push`, JS: `Array.prototype.push`), serialize (PHP: `json_encode`, JS: `JSON.serialize`) and ship as JSON to your app.

Comment: Can you give more details, regarding implemetation of parser.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia That would depend on the language you use. For your case, I'd read the file line by line. There are many questions regarding this here on StackOverflow. You should check them out.